# How to transfer string from listbox to richtextbox

Tags: c#, string, listbox, richtextbox

I have a listbox with a list of strings. When i double click on any string in listbox i want that string to be transferred to the current position of cursor in the richtextbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//DoubleClick event handler for your listBox1
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
   richTextBox1.SelectedText = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this code for client side.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $('select').live('change', function () {
           $("#richTextBox1").val($(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get());
            alert(a);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I needed for c# only. AnyWays thanx for help